# Grid in Kendo not showing

Tags: kendo-ui, grid, kendo-grid

I have the codes below:

```
public class AlphaNumericReportTesting
{
    public string Name  { get; set; }
    public char Sex { get; set; }
    public double Ca { get; set; }
}
```

---

The partial view, sampleView.cshtml

```
@model OnlineReporting.Models.AlphaNumericReportTesting;

<div id="grid"> </div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            data: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)),
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        Name: { type: "string" },
                        Sex: { type: "char" },
                        Ca: { type: "double" }
                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize: 20
        },
        height: 550,
        scrollable: true,
        sortable: true,
        filterable: true,
        pageable: {
            input: true,
            numeric: false
        },
        columns: [
            "Name",
            { field: "Sex", title: "Sex", width: "130px" },
            { field: "Ca", title: " Ca", width: "130px" }
        ]
    });
});
```

---

but when I run the code, I got an error: "Error to retrieve selected report."

How to show my data by having the set up above?

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Kendo There is no Char , double Types make them all string , kendo has type "string, boolean, number"

@model OnlineReporting.Models.AlphaNumericReportTesting;

```
<div id="grid"> </div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            data: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)),
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        Name: { type: "string" },
                        Sex: { type: "string" },
                        Ca: { type: "string" }
                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize: 20
        },
        height: 550,
        scrollable: true,
        sortable: true,
        filterable: true,
        pageable: {
            input: true,
            numeric: false
        },
        columns: [
            { field: "Sex", title: "Sex", width: "130px" },
            { field: "Ca", title: " Ca", width: "130px" }
        ]
    });
});
```

Also "Error to retrieve selected report" is not relevant to Kendo , check your MVC Action for any server Error

Answer (score 0):

This "Error to retrieve selected report" doesn't come from Kendo UI. I suspect there is another problem with your page. Probably a server-side exception.